# Show category by latest post date

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am working in a project where I am using below code to limit number of posts in each category. But I can't figure out how to sort these categories by latest posts. My code is working fine but when I add argument in **wp query array**, it does not sort or it breaks. I want to order the category with most **recent post (date).**

Can anyone guide me?

```html
<?php $terms=g et_terms( array( 'taxonomy'=>'category', 'hide_empty' => false, ) ); foreach($terms as $cat){ $cata_name = $cat->name; $term_id = $cat->term_id; ?>
<?php //echo '<h3>'.$catname[0]->cat_name.'</h3>'; ?>
<?php $catqueryy=n ew WP_Query ( 'cat='.$term_id. '&posts_per_page=5');$count=$ catqueryy->found_posts; ?>
```

Comment: Which SQL DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sort the data when selecting it from the database.  Use an order by and use the date column.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin module... these are my codes from wordpress..

Comment: where u add `argument` ?

Comment: @devpro      <code>   <?php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    
    
foreach($terms as $cat){
 $cata_name = $cat->name; 
 $term_id = $cat->term_id; 
 ?>

Comment: you can use arguments as `$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post', //your_post_type
    'orderby'    => 'date', //meta_value
    'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'cat','value'=>$term_id)),
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add ORDER BY argument in wordpress as:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post', //your_post_type
    'orderby'    => 'date', //meta_value
    'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'cat','value'=>$term_id)),
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$catqueryy = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

*You can explore the wordpress document: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters*

Comment: @Kryptex: ok let me chk

Comment: @Kryptex: read this: http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/ i hope this will help